# Why does import ...RandomForest give "object RandomForest is not a member of package org.apache.spark.mllib.tree"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I worked with the spark implementation of Random Forest in the shell, and this import runs fine:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
```

However, when I try to compile it as a standalone file, it fails. The exact error is:

```
5: object RandomForest is not a member of package org.apache.spark.mllib.tree
```

I have included mllib in my sbt file too, so can someone please tell me where this error arises? My code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest
```

My sbt file:

```
name := "churn"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-core_2.10"              % "1.5.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10"             % "1.5.2"
  )
```

Edit:

```
My-MBP:Churn admin$ sbt 'show libraryDependencies'
[info] Set current project to churn (in build file:/Users/admin/Desktop/Churn/)
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4, org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.1.0, org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:1.1.0)
My-MBP:Churn admin$ sbt scalaVersion
[info] Set current project to churn (in build file:/Users/admin/Desktop/Churn/)
[info] 2.10.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use Spark `1.2.0` or later.

According to the history of [org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/RandomForest.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/commits/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/RandomForest.scala) on GitHub [the first version that supports Random Forest is 1.2.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/0dc2b6361d61b7d94cba3dc83da2abb7e08ba6fe) (see the tags the file was tagged with).

Even though you've showed that your `build.sbt` has `1.5.2` declared, the output of `sbt 'show libraryDependencies'` doesn't confirm it as it says:

> org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.10:1.1.0

`1.1.0` is the effective version of Spark MLlib you use in your project. That version has no support for Random Forest.